# How to save CMD arguments entered in a python file to be executed by default instead of typing them each time?

Tags: python, cmd, arguments, labview

I am working on a GUI on LabVIEW  to command a python application  ( it is a deep learning application) where the user try different parameters via the GUI to specify which parameters fit the best for the training file (arguments via command windows), after figuring out the parameters that give the best results, the user needs to save these parameters as the final ones.. so everytime the training file is executed, it should be executed with the saved Parameters and not with the default ones.. is there any way to save the arguments to be executed as defaults instead of typing them each time ?

Answer (score 1):

Try use `argparse` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

It can set parameter names and default values.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--var1", type=int, default=5)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.var1)
```

Calling with no arguments will print 5.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! but I am sorry I guess I phrased my question wrong.. Actually your answer is what I did to send parameters to the python file , what I need now is to save the arguments that gave me the best results as the default ones, so everytime I call the python file I will not be obliged to enter the arguments again, the arguments should have been saved already.. I was thinking of saving the arguments (maybe the full command line)  in a text file ..

Comment: @asky You can save parsed argument as JSON file with `vars()` function. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object) `import json; with open("args.json", "w", encoding="UTF8") as f: json.dump(vars(args), f)`